# Xbox 360 Play & Charge kit

Tags: controllers

I'm tired of changing batteries of my Xbox controller. I'm considering buying a Play & Charge kit.

- How long until the battery gets unrechargable?
- How long does it take to charge?
- How long does a single charge last?  Longer than batteries?

Comment: I edited your question a bit so that it won't be closed as a shopping recommendation (see the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)).  Hope that's OK.  You should be able to decide whether it's worth it yourself based on the answers, hopefully.

Comment: i had been satisfied with my xbox 360 play and charge kit, until i tripped over it. it is very fragile.

Comment: @Matthew Read - No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a play & charge kit with a 4800 mAh battery. I didn't measure how long exactly it lasts, but I can say that it lasts for quite long. I play up to 10 hours a week, and I charge it in monthly periods. It's been a year since I bought it, and I'm still satisfied.

Another advantage is that you can use your controller while it is getting charged.

Summarizing, I recommend play & charge kits. IMO, they are better than batteries.

Answer (score 3):

How long a single charge lasts varies by game and what else you are using the pad for.  Games with lots of use of the vibration feature will use up the battery faster.  Also if you have a headset or chatpad plugged in that will reduce the battery life since those peripherals need power (however small and nominal an amount) to run.

Main advantage over batteries is that it does last longer (unless you're buying ridiculously expensive top or the range batteries) but that you don't have to have spares on hand since you can charge while playing.  The cable is pretty long so unless you sit miles from your TV you'll easily be able continue playing while it charges

Over time the battery life will reduce but you can still get decent amounts of playtime (10+ hours) out of a pack that is a year or two old - trust me I have racked up days of online play on games like Halo, Call of Duty etc and the analogue stick of the pad wore out before the battery pack did!!

Main things I would recommend is **always** charge the pack up fully when it gets low (and especially the first time you use it - same goes for any rechargeable battery powered device).  You'll get much better life out of the pack this way and it you'll have to charge it less often.

Comment: It lasts longer than regular batteries, certainly, but might be comparable to the life of rechargeable batteries.

Comment: Even so with rechargeable batteries you have to have either have spares on hand pre-charged or wait for a recharge whereas the kit allows you to play while charging which is a big plus for me